# How to mount multiple afp shares?

Tags: macos, mount, network-shares

I have a Mac mini Server with different Users on it. Each of these users have shared folders.

On my MacBook i can only mount with one account of these users from the mac mini server.

Is there a way to mount multiple different afp shares to my MacBook. I don't want to unmount everytime and mount again.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to enter `afp://user1@yourserver` in `Finder`'s connect to server function?

Comment: Which OS version is the MacBook? As far as I recall there was an option from 10.7 to connect as different user when you open the server entry on the left side of a finder window

Comment: Same problem here ( http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273083/mount-shared-drives-with-different-users ), did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Make an Automator workflow like this:

```
1. Get Specified Servers
afp://10.0.0.1:548/folder1
afp://10.0.0.1:548/folder2

2. Connect to Servers
```

Save it as an application, add it to your login items.